# How can I make a navigation menu out of Owl Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

My idea was to make a menu out of Owl Carousel. I have put the Owl Carousel code, etc in all of my folders and the LazyLoad function is currently running on my page. However I can't find out how to make it so that when one of the images (carousels) is clicked on it jumps to the html page that I would want to connect to that image (carousel). Here's some of my code:

```
<section id="demos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page1.png" alt="">
<img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page2.png" alt="">
<img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page3.png" alt="">
<img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page4.png" alt="">
<img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page5.png" alt="">
</div>

<script>
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    center:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    loop:false,
    margin:10
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the image in an anchor?

Comment: Its Probably due to one of the scripts automatically re-writing the page's HTML elements in order to create a specific look / behavior. Try right-clicking on your  Owl Carosel Element and going down to the **Inspect Element** Menu Item _(At the bottom)_, this will allow you to see how your HTML is being modified and might provide a clue as to how you can proceed to implementing your desired functionality

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I managed to use anchors combined with the Inspect Element item, you guys are life savers. Keep on saving ;p.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap Anchor tag around the img tag please find below snippet for more info
or find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/1086/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    center:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    loop:false,
    margin:10
});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <a href="http://google.com"><img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page1.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://google.com"><img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page2.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://google.com"><img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page3.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://google.com"><img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page4.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://google.com"><img class="owl-lazy"  src="Images/Page5.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```